# ¿Por qué no funciona el script secundario?

Tags: jquery

Estoy tratando de hacer una tabla pero si meto el código a un JQuery no me salen las opciones de exportar, ordenar o buscar.
A continuación les muestro el código que estoy tratando de implementar.

**Código**

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Bootstrap 4 Responsive Datatable and Export to PDF, CSV</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/css/buttons.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <script src="https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <div class="col-md-8">


  <div class="container">

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>

  <div id="datos">

    <br>


    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="form-row">
      <label for="idestacion">ID de la estación: </label>
      <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
          <select id="idestacion" name="idestacion" class="custom-select">
              <option value=" ">Selecciona una estación existente</option>
          </select>       
      </div>
  </div>

<button type="submit" id="buscaidestacion" class="btn btn-primary">Buscar</button>


    <br>
    <br>

    <!--<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>-->
    <div class="table-responsive" id="tablaconsulta">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>

      <!-- acabo lo bueno-->
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).on('ready',function (){

   var u1 = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/estaciones/';
   $.ajax({
       url: u1,
       type: 'GET',
       contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
       dataType: "json",
       /* Esto es lo que indica que la respuesta será un objeto JSon */
       success: function(data) {       
       $.each(data, function(index, value) {
           $("#idestacion").append('<option value="' + value.idestacion + '">' + value.nombre + '</option>');
       });  
      } 
    });   
  });


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buscaidestacion").click(function() {
    var idestacion = $("#idestacion").val();
      if ($('#idestacion').val().trim() === '') {
      alert('Debe seleccionar una opción');
      }
      else
      {      
      var idest = idestacion;
      var u = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/registros/' + idest;
      $.ajax({
        url: u,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: "json",
        /* Esto es lo que indica que la respuesta será un objeto JSon */
        success: function(data) {
          /* Vemos que la respuesta no este vacía y sea una arreglo */
          if (data != null && $.isArray(data) && data != 0 ) {
            /* Supongamos que #tblbd es el tbody de tu tabla */
            /* Inicializamos tu tabla */
            $("#tablaconsulta").html(
            '<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" style="width:100%">'+
            '        <thead>'+
            '            <tr>'+
            '                <th>ID</th>'+  
            '                <th>Temperatura</th>'+
            '                <th>Humedad</th>'+
            '                <th>ID de estación</th>'+
            '                <th>Fecha y hora</th>'+
            '            </tr>'+
            '        </thead>'+
            '        <tbody id="tblbd">'
            );
            /* Recorremos tu respuesta con each */
            $.each(data, function(index, value) {
              /* Vamos agregando a nuestra tabla las filas necesarias */
              $("#tblbd").append(
                "<tr>" +
                "<td>" + value.id + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.temperatura + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.humedad + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.estacionid + "</td>" +
                "<td>" + value.created_at + "</td>" +
                "</tr>"
                );
            });

          }
          else
          {
            $("#tablaconsulta").html(
              '<center><p style="color:#FF0000"> No hay datos para mostrar </p></center>'
            );
            alert('No hay datos que mostrar');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});
</script>

    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.5.2/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/responsive.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                lengthChange: false,
                buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'colvis' ]
            } );

            table.buttons().container()
                .appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
        } );
     </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Capturas**

Yo quiero que me salga así

[image: como quiero que salga]

Pero me sale así, si se dan cuenta no salen las flechas de ordenamiento, la busqueda, ni las opciones para exportar.

[image: me sale así]

El código original esta alojado en https://github.com/shubhamgt2/bootstrap-4-responsive-datatable-and-export-to-pdf-csv/blob/master/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu problema esta en como cargar los elementos

Si agregas esta seccion dentro del success te funcionara

```
            var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                lengthChange: false,
                buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'colvis' ]
            } );

            table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
```

Ejemplo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#buscaidestacion").click(function() {
     ...
     success: function(data) {
           # Inserta esto al final
           var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
                lengthChange: false,
                buttons: [ 'copy', 'excel', 'csv', 'pdf', 'colvis' ]
            } );

            table.buttons().container().appendTo( '#example_wrapper .col-md-6:eq(0)' );
}

  });
});
```

Esto te pasa por que al momento de querer generar los botones aun no existe la tabla esta se genera hasta que das el click al boton buscar entonces tienes que meter esa accion al boton "Buscar".

Espero que me haya explicado correctamente